# How to control minimum spacing between objects in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main_bank_button_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"   
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_bank_text"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bank" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_bank_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_bank_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_bank_button"
            android:layout_width="75dp" 
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_bank_progress_bar"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/bank_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using layout_below to place one control below the other. The spacing between controls is more than what I want. How can I reduce it? Possibly having the top of one object touching the bottom of another?

Thank You,
Gary Kipnis

Comment: Why is the width of the RelativeLayout 0dp? Normally when using the `layout_below` attribute there's no space between the **boxes** where the controls are in. You can reduce the space between them by using a negative `layout_marginTop`.

Comment: The width is set to 0 because this RelativeLayout is a component of a LinearLayout (horizontal) where I want these components (there are several of them) to be spaced equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when using the layout_below attribute there's no space between the boxes where the controls are in. You can reduce the space between them by using a negative layout_marginTop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to touch, you can use:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
```

To add space between them, simply increase the value of the attribute.

Comment: adding a margin of "0dp" had no effect, but making margins negative moved the objects closer to each other and achieved the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

By what I can see from your Xml they should already be touching each other. Try setting the background color of the controls to different colors and you'll be sure. In that case it's most likely the controls internal padding, so try setting that to zero.